# zmq: subscriber how to get all the messages from publisher while the publisher closes after sending all messages?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

While the publisher closes after sending all messages, how to get all the messages from publisher on the subscriber side? For example, if I publish 1000 pieces of data, the subscriber gets 500 data pieces. When the publisher finishes with 1000 pieces of data sent, it will close. The subscriber then cannot get data pieces from 501-1000.

Another problem is that when the subscriber joins the topic. It always gets the topic from the first message, not now message. It is different from ROS/ROS2.

I test ZeroMQ publish-subscribe mode in python version. In the past, I used ROS, ROS2, DDS to develop robots.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using XPUB and XSUB. This is exactly the same as PUB / SUB, except that the subscriber has to send a message to subscribe / unsubscribe, and the XPUBlisher can receive these subscribe / unsubscribe messages. See [the API documentation](https://zeromq.org/socket-api/) for details.

That means that you can do this:

**XPUBlisher:**

1. Create and bind socket
2. Wait for all XSUBscriber subscribed messages to come in (one for each subscriber)
3. Send 1000 messages
4. Send a "finished" message
5. Wait for all XSUBscriber unsuscribed messages to come in quit

**XSUBscribers:**

1. Create and connect socket
2. Send subscribe message
3. Read and process messages
4. If the message was "finished", send unsubscribe message
5. quit

This will cause the publisher to hang around until all the subscribers have received the messages that have been sent, quitting only when it knows no subscribers are listening any longer. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

> While the publisher closes after sending all messages, how to get all
> the messages from publisher on the subscriber side? For example, if I
> publish 1000 pieces of data, the subscriber gets 500 data pieces. When
> the publisher finishes with 1000 pieces of data sent, it will close.
> The subscriber then cannot get data pieces from 501-1000.
> The phenomenon is a mistake from bad debug log code.
> The question is meaningless. please ignore the question.
> Thank you for the answer, bazza. I am sorry for it.